# "Entire production" as a collective noun for an artist's works

Tags: phrases, expressions, terminology

Is it common or possible to use the construction "The **entire production** of an artist is on display at the museum", or is there another collective noun that encompasses the entirety of an artist's works without referring to the art format (e.g. cinematography, photography, discography)?

Answer (score 4):

**Oeuvre** is a word borrowed from French that means the entirety of an artist's work without specifying the medium. It can also refer to the artist's overall style.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oeuvre

Answer (score 0):

A term often used for [visual arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_arts#The_Renaissance) is:

[Retrospective](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retrospective):

> a show of the work an artist has done in their life so far:
>
> - a Hockney retrospective/a retrospective of Hockney's works.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

In literature, the expression used is [The Complete Works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works)

> - a collection of all the works of one artist, writer, musician, group, etc. Sometimes the Latin language equivalent, ***[Opera Omnia](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opera%20omnia)***.

(M-W, Wikipedia)

Comment: Thank you, although I must specify that the above context I provided does not represent the actual context quite accurately. It is rather more bureaucratic and about copyrights and prohibiting the copying of an artist's works. I suppose "Complete works" might work in this case.